# Responsividade de colunas no BootStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho duas linhas com duas colunas, a primeira coluna da primeira linha tem uma imagem e a segunda coluna dessa linha tem um texto. A segunda linha tem um texto na primeira coluna e uma imagem na segunda.

Quando a responsividade acontece, fica imagem e texto um embaixo do outro e depois texto e imagem um embaixo do outro.

Eu preciso que quando ocorrer a responsividade, fique imagem e texto um embaixo do outro.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Oi! Você pode mandar o trecho de código ou uma imagem de como deveria ficar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com Bootstrap3 vc pode fazer usando `display:flex` e `column-reverse` apenas para as resoluções pequenas usando a medida @media do Bootstrap.

Veja como fica no exemplo abaixo. ***Mande exibir como "Pagina toda" para ver funcionando!***

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, iure ab eos iste cum quam quo voluptatibus! Quae, dolor placeat?
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row reverse">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe expedita iure nesciunt, modi voluptate corporis voluptatum sunt ducimus magni delectus.
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/101" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Para o Bootstrap 4 basta vc trocar a **`order`** dos elementos na medida `@media` que vc quiser. No caso na menor medida oficial `577px` eu troquei a ordem, ***pois o grid do Bootstrap 4 já é flex por default***

Veja como fica. ***OBS:*** Como a medida é 577px aqui ainda aparece um do lado do outro, mas se a tela for menor que isso vai quebrar direitinho, é só testar ai.

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm-6.reverse {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, iure ab eos iste cum quam quo voluptatibus! Quae, dolor placeat?
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 reverse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe expedita iure nesciunt, modi voluptate corporis voluptatum sunt ducimus magni delectus.
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/101" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque a grade do bs usa alinhamento a esquerda, então realmente vai ficar imagem->texto->texto->imagem, mas você pode criar uma classe css específica para essas colunas usando `@media{}`, por exemplo:

Essas são as @media utilizadas pelo bootstrap4

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Então para dispositivos menores você pode fazer assim:

Primeiramente, definir o elemento `pai` com `display:flex;` e `flex-direction: column;`, depois definir a ordem da coluna:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {//aqui você ajusta o tamanho máximo do display para ter a alteração
    .alinhamento{
        order:2;
    }
}
```

Basta atribuir a classe a coluna desejada, e a ordem será invertida.

EDIT: Claro que as alterações deverão ser feitas de acordo com a necessidade do seu código e da quantidade de elementos que você gostaria de alterar a ordem, relacionando seus posicionamentos no elemento pai.

Comment: Jovem não precisa colocar display flex é só colocar o *order*, pois o grid do BS4 já é *flex* por default

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl, eu não tinha conhecimento disso, gratidão!

Comment: Tranquilo olha ali que na resposta que inclui um exemplo, repara que é só colocar o `order` e já é.

Comment: Então, pude ver só dps que comentei, pois comentamos ao mesmo tempo, mas bom que ficam dois aprendizados.

Comment: Depois da uma olhada no Utilites do BS4, la tem várias classes prontas para usar com display flex, olha ai https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Vou olhar sim, obrigado mais uma vez.