# Duvidas de responsividade

Tags: layout-responsivo

Estou com um problema e preciso de ajuda
Tenho uma área no site em que tem o que a empresa faz,no caso não é esse da imagem, é só um exemplo que tenho.

No caso da imagem um temos 
Imagem + Texto
Texto + Imagem

e quando você olha na responsividade o mesmo fica do mesmo padrão conforme a foto dois

No meu caso quando vou fazer os testes de responsividade fica
Imagem + Texto + Texto + Imagem

Como posso fazer para na hora da responsividade ele manter o padrão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
N

Código:

### Sites 
Teste

TTeste

```
</div><!-- /.row -->    
</div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->



  <!--segundo-->        
  <div class="inner_section"> 
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 about-us fadeInRight animated wow delay-50s">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <br><br><br><br>
                  <p>
                    <div class="text fadeInLeft animated wow delay-60s" > 
                   <h2> Teste</h2><br>
                  <h6>Teste.</h6> </p>
                  </div>          
                  </ul><!-- /.about-us-list -->

                </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="img/icons-am2.png" align="">
```

```
</div><!-- /.row -->    
</div>
```

Comment: Vc esta cuando bootstrap?

Comment: Sim!
Estou usando bootstrap v3.3.1

Comment: Essas duas respostas vão te ajudar a resolver o problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386335/alterar-a-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-dos-textos-s%c3%b3-em-html/386342#386342 e qui tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295950/responsividade-de-colunas-no-bootstrap/295969#295969

Comment: Ajudou demais,

Obrigado amigo!